# Is there any way we can call another function after the ajax call completed?

Tags: javascript, ajax, asynchronous

Is there any way we can call another function after the ajax call completed?
I don't want to call it from success handler of ajax, as this ajax call is used in multiple areas, so it will be messy making switch from there?
Right now I am doing  it in a bad way by using set timeout on this ajax call statement and executing next action within timeout.

problem:

```
function my_ajax(){
```

//ajax call goes here....
}

palce of calling:
my_ajax();
statement 1;

another place of calling:
my_ajax();
statement2;

any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: seems weird you would not call it from success.... maybe use promises. Are you using jQuery because you said `success` ?

Comment: Your senario makes no sense. Basically you have two calls to the same function that makes an Ajax call and you want to do something different with them?

Comment: There's something i can't understand on your question, can you show some code sample?

Comment: hope this helps. I just need to call the ajax from multiple areas and want to execute something else after it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming jQuery here as well, but you could wrap your ajax in a function.

```
function myAjax() { 
  return $.ajax(/* ... */)
}

const ajaxOne = myAjax();
ajaxOne.done(function() { /* do stuff one */ })

const ajaxTwo = myAjax();
ajaxTwo.done(functiion() { /* do stuff two */ })
```

## edit

riffing off this a bit you could pass in your success/fail functions as callbacks

```
function myAjax(success, fail) {
  const error = (fail !== undefined) 
    ? fail 
    : function(err) { console.error(err) };

  return $.ajax(/* ... */)
    .done(success)
    .fail(error);
}
```

Comment: jQuery provide "when" method for this practices

Comment: @Sk. I thought they might have their own version of promise architecture, but I haven't used jQuery in quite a while so didn't know it offhand. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use .always(), if your next call after ajax should be called all the time.

```
// Assign handlers immediately after making the request,
// and remember the jqXHR object for this request
var jqxhr = $.ajax( "example.php" )
  .done(function() {
    alert( "success" );
  })
  .fail(function() {
    alert( "error" );
  })
  .always(function() {
    alert( "complete" );
  });
```

Source : http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: no, as I told above, I want it to call for specific scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

You can encapsulate your ajax with a function that accepts a callback as argument:

```
function my_ajax(callback) {
    $.ajax('example.php').done(callback)
}
```

Then, you can call it with the callback you want:

```
// Will log 'AAA' on success of this request
my_ajax(function() { console.log('AAA') })

// Will log 'BBB' on success of this request
my_ajax(function() { console.log('BBB') })
```

Answer (score 0):

So return the Ajax object back and use it to assign the custom done method.

```
function myAjax() {
  return $.ajax( "fooPath" )
}

myAjax.done(function () { console.log(1) })
myAjax.done(function () { console.log(2) })
```

Answer (score 0):

ajax is asynchronous, by default..
if i understand you need to wait the full response of one ajax, and use in other ajax...

with native jascript this type of work is some complex.... can be resolve with **setInterval** and **clearInterval**,

**the idea**

i worked in the past with globals vars.
setInterval, define a continous execution a customfunction, and return an id, to stop them in the future..... Now inside of your custom fuction then you define two condition, the first is stop clausses ( your first ajax is not complete  ) and else ...execute the second ajax...and the clearInterval for stop continous execution

Of course **jQuery** provide and easy way to do this... is called ... "when"..

```
$.when( $.ajax( "test.php" ) ).then(function( data, textStatus, jqXHR ) {
  // here ajax2 
  $.ajax( "test2.php" )
});
```